# Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database instance | Google App engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Unable to Connect to the cloud sql | Google App engine |
Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database instance error.

I did read this tutorial
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

I tried to give my appID to Storage>>cloudsql>>Authorized App Engine Applications, but it shows me this

> Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database
>   instance.

Comment: "Authorized GAE applications must be in the same region as the database instance." is the clue. Can you move either the application or the database to the same region?

Comment: @TonyTseng please tell me how to move it to same region. Actually what it means 'must be in the same region'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the cloud sql console at: https://console.developers.google.com/project/<project_id>/sql/instances

This will show your list of Cloud Sql instances.  There's a column for region in the list that will tell you what region each instance is in.

I'm not sure offhand how to verify the region of an appengine app, but in order to be in EU you'd have to have premier account.